# PIL Resizes Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I have this code

```
from PIL import Image

def get_concat_h_cut(im1, im2):
   dst = Image.new('RGB', (im1.width + im2.width,
                           min(im1.height, im2.height)))
   dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
   dst.paste(im2, (im1.width, 0))
   return dst


def get_concat_v_cut(im1, im2):
   dst = Image.new(
       'RGB', (min(im1.width, im2.width), im1.height + im2.height))
   dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
   dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
   return dst

FileA = Image.open("dog.jpg")
FileB = Image.open("cat.jpg")

get_concat_v_cut(FileA, FileB).save('pillow_concat_v_cut.jpg')
```

But since the reolsution of the cat image is small, the program resizes the entire image, thus I can't see most of the dog image. How do I make it so I can see both the cat and dog?

Cat image: https://i.ibb.co/j58TRnt/cat.jpg

Dog image: https://i.ibb.co/d6jdsBC/dog.jpg

Image that the program generates: https://i.ibb.co/WkDdPTD/pillow-concat-v-cut.jpg

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you want differently sized images to be handled — saying you both to visible isn's specific enough. Can one or both be resized, of example?

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep the width of the dog image the same, which will fill in black space to the right of the cat image on the output image, you can change the size argument for Image.new in your concat function to
`(max(im1.width, im2.width), im1.height+im2.height)`

The same would apply to your h-cut concat function, just applied to the height argument.

If you're trying to scale them to the same size, you can invoke the .resize() method on whichever one you want to scale, and pass it the other image's height and width variables as it's size argument.

You can find more info here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.resize

Comment: Thank you!! how do I make it so there is some space between the two images, and how do I make the black part invisible?